# How can I use Ninject WCF extension with a singleton service?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, ninject, ninject-extensions

I'm using Ninject 2.2.1.4 and Ninject.Extensions.Wcf 2.2.0.4.

My service is decorated with the following attribute:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
```

Using the above attribute, I receive the error:

> "The service type provided could not be loaded as a service because it does not have a default (parameter-less) constructor. To fix the problem, add a default constructor to the type, or pass an instance of the type to the host."

If I remove the attribute Ninject works as expected.

After doing some research it's my understanding that since the service is marked as a singleton it will automatically be created with a parameter-less constructor by the ServiceHost, hence the error message.  In order to resolve the issue, I have to create the service object myself, resolved using ninject, and then pass that singleton object off to the ServiceHost to use.  I'm not sure how to do that.

I looked at the WCF extension source and I see that NinjectServiceHost inherits from ServiceHost, so my thought was to bind NinjectServiceHost to my instance of the service object using the overloaded constructor:

```
 public NinjectServiceHost( object singletonInstance )
        : base( singletonInstance )
    {
    }
```

I'm not sure if that's correct and if it is, how and where to properly bind it so the ServiceHost can be fed my instance.

Any suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with a beta Version I suggest to update to 2.3.x It supports IIS hosted singleton Services. See also the examples on github

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that.  Do you have an idea when it will come out of beta?

Comment: No. I don't give any dates. While I know quite exactly how much work is left for the next release, I have absolutely no idea about how much time I can spend on Ninject.
But regarding WCF there shouldn't change anything. The only thing that is added to other assemblies for WCF is support for InRequestScope for the XML and Conventions extensions.